# SQL Server Cursor preceed by IF statement?

Tags: sql-server, cursors

The SELECT statement to populate my Sql Server CURSOR can (often) return zero rows.

Is it advisable to enclose it within an IF check so the CURSOR it is not Declared, Opened, Closed, & Deallocated ?

Or will the RDMS automatically know not to create the CURSOR and/or does an IF based on the exact same SELECT infer the query processing twice?

Comment: The best approach would be to avoid cursors entirely. SQL is an iterative language and really does not do row by agonizing row processing well at all.

Comment: Re: Cursor avoidance https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/330338/sql-server-stored-proc-locking-serialization -- When I do a set based insert the cashbalance field updates based on a SELECT that is reused by the RDMS.  Hence a cashbalance field that say started at $0 might be subtracted by one and thus have $-1 in the first inserted row.  If then in the second inserted row +1 is added, because both inserts reference the initial $0 SELECTED value the second row inserts a cashbalance of $1 (i.e. not 0-1+1=0 as it should be).  But I'm admittedly far from experienced in SQL or architecture.

Comment: @MS: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you're saying.  Please edit your question with an example of a few rows of data, the query you're running, the results you're getting, and what you'd like to get instead.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades I don't mean to be insolent but J.D. understood and answered the question immediately.  After which I marked his response as the answer, thanked him and moved on.  Fourteen days later you critique, close and downvote the post.  I'm pretty newb but is there some etiquette I am missing?

Comment: Good!  I can only speak for myself in saying that you're question seemed very vague; while it's great that you did get an answer, you should probably include more details, such as sample rows, in the future.

Comment: The way close votes work is that there is a queue of questions which have been flagged.  People above a certain amount of rep can view this queue and then vote to close or vote to keep open, as well as making comments or edits.  Once five people have voted to close, it gets closed - but can be reopened if the question is edited.  It's not immediately obvious if there are answers (let alone good ones), and on a medium-sized Exchange like this it can take weeks for a consensus to form from the small number of people perusing the close queue.

Comment: Keep in mind is that Stack Exchange aims to be not just a place where *your* question gets answered, but where questions and answers can benefit people in the future.  Again, I'm glad that your question was clear enough for you to get an answer, but consider someone with a related question who comes across this in a search result.  Will they be able to tell if this relates to their problem?  That's part of why SE is so tightly moderated compared to, say, Reddit, or most forums, where conversations are assumed to be ephemeral.  If it helps any, I've had plenty of my questions closed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it advisable to enclose it within an IF check so the CURSOR it is not Declared, Opened, Closed, & Deallocated ?

If the source dataset for the cursor contains 0 rows, then these steps of the cursor are very minimal and negligible. I wouldn't worry about coding an `IF` statement for it.

> does an IF based on the exact same SELECT infer the query processing twice?

Yes, that'll cause the `SELECT` query to run twice, which depending on the query, can be measurably resource intensive and potentially lock the underlying tables twice as much. So you are better off not doing this.

If you were to do this, you'd be better off running the `SELECT` query once and storing the results in a temp table. That way you can re-use the results from the temp table later on, if there were any. But as mentioned earlier, I think an `IF` statement is unnecessary anyway.

Comment: Thank you, that is precisely the information I was looking for.